# Why do this errors occur in Docker?

Tags: docker

I am trying to install this program for my master thesis; 
https://github.com/gioargyr/docker-kr-suite but i can't understand how 
exactly run it. I have cloned it, then run this command in termninal as README mentioned; "[sudo] docker build -t docker-image-name ." Then these errors occured. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HOvO.jpg

Do you have any idea how to install and run this program appropriately?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please copy and paste the text from the terminal (including the command, ouput and errors) into **your question** above. Do not put images of texts.

Comment: I am using Disco Dingo.

Comment: Disco is not released yet and thus off-topic. Why do you have "trusty" repositories in your sources? Those won't work for Disco.

Comment: I tried it with trusty version also.

Comment: Is the screenshot from trusty or disco?

Comment: It is from Disco.

Comment: I can only say that you have a problem, as there should not be any trusty in disco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

To check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

Optional: add $USER to docker group (make sure to log out and back in after)

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks for answer again.

Comment: Can You accept the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    # This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
listen_addresses='*'
2019-04-08 17:22:57.038 UTC [13] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-04-08 17:08:00 UTC
2019-04-08 17:22:57.296 UTC [13] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-04-08 17:22:57.299 UTC [17] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-04-08 17:22:57.299 UTC [12] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

After solving problem; i run "docker run " and i take these lines. How can i use it, because once i run a command like "ls" nothing happened.

Comment: You need to make a user for docker. Also to see the commands type just “docker”.

Comment: how can i make a user?

Comment: Check optional in my answer.

Comment: What happens when you type: “docker run hello-world”

Comment: "Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
"

Comment: So its working

Comment: But i cant find how to use docker-kr-suite :D

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://docker-curriculum.com/

Comment: If you got any further questions ask a new question. Because i can’t aswer properly in a comment

Comment: I stuck after "docker run <repository>"

Comment: Try rebooting. Maybe there are unsolved operatione. Btw, as i said, ask new question, so i can answer properly.

Comment: I am asking now.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions

Comment: i asked you can check my profile.

Comment: after reboot my pc my repo is gone

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. This seems to be a separate issue arising from the solution you were given for the first issue. So please ask a new question about it.